# Ping : Name or service not known

Tags: bash, ping

So i am creating this bash script but it is giving me an error that ** name or service not known .**

[image]

The code is :

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$1" == "" ]
then
echo "Hello"
echo "Bye"
else
for x in 'seq 1 254' ;  do
ping -c 1 $1.$x
done
fi
```

Comment: When you have text output, [don't take a picture but copy paste the output in your POST](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using single quote instead of backticks for your seq statement.

```
for x in 'seq 1 254'
```

Will result in 3 items: seq, 1, 254

```
for x in `seq 1 254`
```

Will result in: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, etc..

Single quotes are for literals, backticks are for command substitution.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into existing tools which can do ping sweeps, rather than rolling your own. `nmap` for example with its -sn option. https://linux.die.net/man/1/nmap